# Navigate up a node from document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the node or class above the document.getElementsByClassName
For example

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="z">
    <div class="3">
    </div>
</div>
```

after doing

```
document.getElementsByClassName("3")
```

is there a way to navigate to class a and z. Like if i wanted to change the color of the entire a and z class not just the 3 class.

Comment: What research have you done?  DOM traversal is very heavily documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `.parentNode`

For `.parentNode`, if you are using `getElementsByClassName` (which returns an array) you would have to loop through the array.

something along the lines of (pardon if too verbose, I am an iOS Engineer by trade):

```
var elementsOfClassThree = document.getElementsByClassName("3");
for (var i = 0; i < elementsOfClassThree.length; i ++) {
    var parentElement = elementsOfClassThree[i].parentNode
    parentElement.style.color = "blue"
}
```